# Apex format function returning weird dates

Tags: apex, datetime, formatting

I am attaching a screenshot which shows a code sample and it's output also. When I normally debug the created date it shows me correct output and then when I try to format it using format function it shows weird behaviour. In the example, it is showing 17 Feb as 48 Feb. I am not able to understand whether I am doing something wrong or it is a salesforce bug. Please share your ideas and solutions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation for **[`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)**. You need to use lower `d`, not upper `D` if you wish to get the day in month.

```
Letter    Date or Time Component    Presentation    Examples
D         Day in year               Number          189
d         Day in month              Number          10
```

Please note that the documentation on [`Datetime`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) indicates which format is used.

> **format(dateFormatString)**
>   Converts the date to the local time zone and returns the converted date as a string using the supplied Java simple date format. If the time zone cannot be determined, GMT is used.